# Error running Phalcon Web App

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, phalcon, web-development-server

I have been given a web site to edit but I cant start it yet. Im using Apache and MySql. The site is live and seems to work just fine. But when I start it localy
I get the following message:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault::$di in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\app.php on line 167

Fatal error: Call to a member function getShared() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\app.php on line 167
```

**Code:**

```
protected function initDispatcher( $options = [] ) {

  $this->di['dispatcher'] = function() {

  $eventsManager = $this->di->getShared( 'eventsManager' );
  $eventsManager->attach( 'dispatch:beforeDispatch' , new Security( $this->di ) );

  $dispatcher = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
  $dispatcher->setEventsManager( $eventsManager );

  return $dispatcher;
};
```

**Edit:**
I started it on PhpStorm now didnt have one, so there are few errors I couldnt notice on Notepad++. It says that it doesnt recognize Phalcon namespace. Which makes all other Phalcon classes unusable.

So that leads me to the next question - How can I define the namespace Phalcon in a project?

Comment: Try phpinfo() and search for phalcon do you see it? If not, you did not install it correctly. Did you restart your apache after adding the extension to php.ini?

Comment: I see it. I restarted the apache many times after the installation.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps life site uses different php/phalcon version from your local environment? Is it possible to share code portion from your app.php? It all looks like an installation problem.. strange.

Comment: Just posted the function that gives error. I also think that its an installation problem because I still dont understand back-end completely and I installed it by myself.

Comment: Problem is that $this->di is not set before you call initDispatcher(). My suggestion is to start debugging row by row from the beginning of your bootstrap file. Check for wrong paths in includes e.t.c. perhaps the guys before you hard coded stuff which works only for the life server setup..

Comment: I started it on PhpStorm now didnt have one, so there are few errors I couldnt notice on Notepad++. It says that it doesnt recognize Phalcon namespace. Which makes all other Phalcon classes unusable. How can I define the namespace Phalcon in a project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107114/discussion-between-niki-mihaylov-and-todor-atanasov).